# What does @ in front of a directory name imply?

Tags: directory, ls

On my Synology NAS, when I do `ls` on my volume, I see that a few directories a leading `@` in their names. A few also have a trailing `@`.

What does this imply?

Examples:

- `@optware`
- `@autoupdate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing.

It's a valid character in the filename. I would assume that Synology has used the `@` character in its "internal use" directory names to avoid a possible name clash with any directory names you or your users might use.